# Conversion of Vector<Vector> to a String Array or a String[][]

Tags: java, vector, jtable

I have a JTable containing only one columns of , called "Points"
[Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5uxa.png)

I have another JTable containing seven columns of , called "Lines"
[Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECGoK.png)

I am writing a button handler that removes every point (row) in Points which is not found in Lines as it is not utilized.

I extract the content of Points one point (row) at a time.
I extract the entire content of Lines ideally in a String Array. Unluckily the method I use with Lines outputs a Vector. I cannot find a way to convert from Vector to String Array or similar data type.
My goal is to search in Lines for the single point from Points without using nested loops.
I tried the following instructions but they do not work. Presumably because the method "contains()" does not work when searching a Vector.
I would greatly appreciate some suggestion. Thank you in advance.

I tried the following:

```
        btnDeleteUnused.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
               Vector<Vector> data =  linesTableModel.getDataVector();
                for(int k = pointsTableModel.getRowCount() - 1; k >= 0; k--)
                {
                     String pn = (String) pointsTableModel.getValueAt(k, 0);    // Fetch Point Name at (k_th row, column 0)
                     System.out.println("Current Point:  "+ pn);
                     System.out.println(data.contains(pn));
                }
                // TO BE DEVELOPED 
            }
        });
```

Comment: You would only need one _loop_.

Answer (score 0):

You do indeed have a problem with using `contains` on your `data` Object. It results because you are attempting to search for, presumably, a `String`, but each element of `data` is *not* a `String`. Each element is another `Vector`. The `data` variable is essentially a 2D Vector. Thus, `data.contains(pn)` is searching for a `String` that is the same as a row of `Vectors`, so will always return `false`.

An analogy: Think of `data` as a case. The case contains some number of boxes of candy. But, the lists of types of candy is missing. You want to find whether or not the case contains any caramel candy. The code in the question using `data.contains(pn)` is like going through the case, picking out one-box-at-a-time, and asking "Is this *box* a piece of caramel?" To find out if the case contains any caramel candy, you want to open each box, and then check each piece in that box.

To access a single element of a `Vector<Vector>`, you need to use two indexes. See the [example in the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getDataVector--).

So, to search for a specific `String`, you need to search element-by-element with nested loops, or use `contains` within a loop.

The following method can be used to find the first location of an occurrence of a target `String.` This uses the `contains` method within a loop. It returns an `int []` with two elements: One for the outer index, the other for the inner index:

```
public static int [] indexOf (Vector<Vector> theVector, String target) {
    for (int outer = 0; outer < theVector.size (); outer++) { 
        int inner = theVector.get(outer).indexOf (target);
        if (inner >= 0) { 
            return new int [] {outer, inner};
        }
    }
    return new int [] { -1, -1};
}
```

Following is a refactored `indexOf (Vector<Vector> theVector, String target)` method. Instead of using `contains`, the code shows how each element might be accessed. The code uses some intermediate variables, which should make it easier to follow.

It also fixes another issue, which is explained after the code sample:

```
public static int [] indexOf (Vector<Vector> vectorVector, String target) {
    for (int outer = 0; outer < vectorVector.size (); outer++) { 
        Vector rowVect = vectorVector.get(outer);
        for (int inner = 0; inner < rowVect.size(); inner++) {
            Object obj = rowVect.get(inner);
            if (obj.toString().equalsIgnoreCase (target)) {
                return new int [] { outer, inner};
            }
        }
    }
    return new int [] { -1, -1};
}
```

The other issues is this:

An element of `JTable` does not necessarily have to be a `String`. So, it isn't necessarily the case that each element of `data` is a `String`. An element of `data` might be, hypothetically, a `Foo`. Suppose your code is looking for an element of `data` that corresponds to `"Eleven"`. It so happens, the `Eleven` is actually associated with the `Foo`, because its `toString()` method returns `"Eleven"`. The first version won't work. The refactored version solves this by using `String#equals` method.

Note that the refactored version actually uses `.equalsIgnoreCase` to illustrate the revision makes that possible.

Your code has

`System.out.println(data.contains(pn));`.

You could use the above method by changing that line to

`System.out.println(indexOf (data, pn)[0] != -1);`

When you develop more code, you could access the specific element like this:

```
int [] location = indexOf (data, pn);
if (location [0] >= 0) {
    String foo = data.get(location[0]).get(location[1]);
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive solution. There is only one glitch. Java does not accept the comparison which is the argument of println. I believe the comparison is between a vector with two elements ans a scalar

Comment: Ooops -- That `println` statement was missing a subscript:  `System.out.println(indexOf (data, pn)[0] != -1);`

Comment: No worry. Your code is excellent. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Can your code be used to extract data from a JTable with only one column? Thank you

Comment: @EdelweissMonville, Sure. You still have a `Vector<Vector>`. But, the loop for `outer` will iterate only one time. The only valid value for index `outer` will be `0`.

Comment: By the way, it would have been easier to understand if the return type of `linesTableModel.getDataVector();` were `Vector<Vector<Object>>`. But, the maintainers of Java didn't do it that way.

Comment: Thank you so much.   Why cannot the data from a JTable be declared Vector<Vector<String>> ?

Comment: @EdelweissMonville Take a look at the brief Oracle [JTable tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), where a JTable row in the example represents 3 `String` Objects, an `Integer` Object, and `Boolean` Object. The data item represented by a cell is not necessarily a `String`.  So,  to allow for the possibility a cell contains a non-String, the `~.getDataVector()` method cannot be a `Vector<Vector<String>>`.  That's why the code in my example uses `toString()`

Comment: Why it can't be declared `Vector<Vector<Object>>` is beyond me.

Comment: Thank you. I will read the documentation you mentioned. I started developing a Java GUI after watching videos from an introductory Java online course.  My experience is still shallow. Thank God there are some knowledgeable generous professionals like you out there.

Comment: I am grateful for your algorithm that finds the first occurrence of a string in a JTable.                                                                                                                 
I wonder how to modify your algorithm so as it searches for the second occurrence, the third, and  so on.                                                      
Alternatively I wonder if the algorithm could still find only the first occurrence of the string but not searching through the whole JTable but instead through a subset of its rows and columns.

Comment: @EdelweissMonville You could add a parameter. Initialize a counter before the outer loop. In the inner loop, when there is a match, increment the counter. And then test if the parameter is `==` the counter.  But, before you do that, think about what should happen if, for example, you are trying to find the 4th occurrence, but the table contains only 2.

Comment: If you want to search only a subset of rows and columns -- a subtable -- you could add parameters specifying the limits of the subtable.

Comment: I called your method to recursively remove the rows that depend on a row being deleted.   If a geometrical entity, like a Point, is deleted by the user then all the Lines containing the Point must be removed

Comment: Before calling your method I had to remove the row where the string occurrence was found reducing the search range.  I was thinking of trying to extract the Vector<Vector> data from a subtable rather than from the whole table but I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In my other answer, I tried to explain how to search for a specific `String` value in the `data` variable  in
`Vector<Vector> data =  linesTableModel.getDataVector();` I took that to be what you actually asking. This answer, instead, addresses the question header, and ignores the question body.

Keeping in mind that `data` is a `Vector` in which each element is another `Vector`, you can convert its contents to a 2D array using nested loops. Here is code for such a method:

```
public static String [][] VectorToString2D (Vector<Vector> vect) { 
    String [][] result = new String [vect.size()][];
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < vect.size(); rowIndex++) {
        Vector vectRow = vect.get(rowIndex);
        String [] stringRow = new String [vectRow.size()];
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < vectRow.size(); columnIndex++) {
            stringRow [columnIndex] = vectRow.get(columnIndex).toString();
        }
        result [rowIndex] = stringRow;
    }        
    return result;
}
```

As in the previous answer, this uses `toString` to allow for the possibility that elements in `data` are not necessarily `String` Objects.